# Why copy an NSString instead of just retaining it?

Tags: objective-c

by now i was always did the same :

```
 NSString *ran = @"check";
```

now when i wanted to copy an nsstring1 to nsstring2 , i have been told here that i have to copy/retain the nsstring instance, in a various methods(with property retain/copy) ..

```
NSString *animation = [ran copy];
```

i know and understand how to do that , but cant understand why .

what exactly happen with the memory here? i just couldnt understand what happen when i do the copy/retain thing , and when should i do that ? (in the above first exampe also?? )

all explanations here are about the difference between copy/retain , but i couldnt found anything about the REASON , i have to copy a class instance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would copy a string if you need it to be immutable, and you don't know if it is immutable.  Say you have this method:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    _name = [newName retain];
}
```

You expect me to call your method like this:

```
[yourObject setName:@"Rob"];
```

But I might instead do this:

```
NSMutableString *sneaky = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Rob"];
[yourObject setName:sneaky];
```

and then a while later I might do this:

```
[sneaky appendString:@"ert"];
// sneaky is now @"Robert"
```

Since your `setName:` method only retained the string it was passed, I have changed the value of your private `_name` variable without you knowing about it.  Maybe you were depending on it not changing.

To prevent such sneakiness, you can write your `setName:` method like this:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    _name = [newName copy];
}
```

Now you create an immutable copy of whatever name I pass in.  If I pass in a mutable string, and then change it, your `_name` won't be affected.

Comment: WOW thanks a lot! thats a really good explanation! , but now, what about the release? when and WHY should i release that newName? and why using retain anyway ?

Comment: another thing, in your example, why couldnt i do in the setname: _name=newName ? why i do need the retain for this ?

Comment: You need to retain to let the system know you want the object to stay around.  Otherwise it might deallocate it.  You release the object when you're done with it so the system knows it can deallocate it (if nobody else wants it).  If you use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), you don't have to do retain or release.  ARC is available in Mac OS X 10.7 and iOS 5.0.